# Using Google chart API with Google static maps

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to display a bubble using Google chart API on the Google
static maps and am running into an issue.  The URL (A) below shows
fine on the map whereas URL (B) below does not show the bubble.  The
only difference between the two URLs is 'B' shows "V speedis" instead
of "V speed".  Any suggestion why (B) is not working?

The bubble that I want to display should have the text "Victor, lat:0.50, speed: 30".  I have URL encoded it but its not working.

Any help with be much appreciated!

(A) Show the text "V speed" in the bubble
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=12&size=912x912&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_text_small%26chld=bb%257CV%2520speed%257CFFFF88%257C000000|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false

(B) Show the text "V speedis" in the bubble
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=12&size=912x912&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_text_small%26chld=bb%257CV%2520speedis%257CFFFF88%257C000000|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In loading custom icon markers there is a [maximum size of 4096 pixels](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/%23CustomIcons).

- Your first image (V speed) is 85x42 = 3570px
- Your second (V speedis) is 99x42 = 4158px